# How can I get the JSON content of individual settings from VS Code workspace settings UI and the applicable file(s) they are stored in?

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings

`VSCode > File > Preferences > Settings > Workspace` allows one to view and modify a number of settings.

Is there a way to show what the corresponding `.json` text is and in what file?

Comment: click the `open json` button in the top right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the gear menu of each setting in the settings UI (use the `Preferences: Open Settings (UI)` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)), there's an option to "Copy Setting as JSON". You can also open your user settings.json file using the `Preferences: Open Settings JSON (JSON)` command, or your workspace's .vscode/settings.json, or if you are using a multi-root workspace, its .code-workspace file. If you want to look at system defaults, use the `Preferences: Open Default Settings (JSON)` command.

The Settings UI has a user scope tab, and a workspace scope tab. The workspace tab will also mention if the setting is also set at another scope, such as the user scope.